# Is every vector space a proper subspace of a larger vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Is every vector space a proper subspace of a larger vector space?

I would think this is true, but was unable to come up with a construction.

Comment: Up to isomorphism, yes, as long as the space itself isn't trivial.  Just add a dimension by $- \times \mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is your ground field.

Comment: I suppose you mean proper subspace, i.e. it is imbedded in a strictly larger vector space.  Of course, if your vector space is $V$, take $V \oplus X$, where $X$ is some other vector space, not the zero vector space.

Comment: To continue @fredgoodman's thought, trivial subspace normally means a subspace containing only the zero vector.  So in that context the trivial subspace remains a trivial subspace no matter what "larger vector space" includes it.

Comment: I mean with non-trivial proper for the inclusion relation. Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sketch of a concrete construction using the existence of free vector spaces over a given set and cantors theorem.

Let K be a field an M be a set.

**Definition**

> A free K vector space over M is a K vector space that has M as a basis.

**Theorem**

> There is a free K vector space over M

**Sketch of proof:**

> Consider the set $K^{(M)}:=\{f:M\to K~|~|f^{-1}(K\setminus\{0\})|\in\mathbb N\}$ of functions that take only finitely many values $\neq 0$.
>
> This is a vector space of dimension $|M|$ since the characteristic functions $\chi_{\{m\}}:M\to K$ for $m\in M$ form a basis.
>
> The only problem is, that M is not a subset of that space. By "exchanging" $\chi_{\{m\}}$ with m for every m we get a new vector space with M as a basis (make sure you understand why this works!).

Now we know that for any set M there is a K vector space V that has M as a basis. This reduces your question
to the following:

> For a given set M, ist there a superset N with strictly bigger cardinality?

If so, take a free K vector space over that set and you are done.

The answer to that question is "yes". First of all note that cantor's theorem states $|\mathfrak{P}(M)|>|M|$ (the proof is easy and can be
found on wikipedia). Swap every $\{m\}\in \mathfrak P(M)$ with m to obtain a set with the cardinality of $\mathfrak{P}(M)$
with M as a subset (again, make sure to make sense of my sloppiness!).

I hope this answers your question to your satisfaction, feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Greetings, Tobi

PS: I'm not a native English speaker and I'm not used to writing mathematics in English. Also, this is my first answer on math.stackexchange. I hope my text is intelligible and up to standards and would gladly receive any feedback concerning that.

Comment: Due to lack of reputation I cant comment on user8734617's post. He nicely explains the parts I left out, but I think that his construction only works in the finite-dimensional case. Adding one vector to the basis in the infinite case doesn't increase the cardinality. That's why I used cantor's theorem.

Comment: I am familiar with the construction of free vector space and cantor's theorem. Your answer certainly meets the standards. Very great first answer! (+1)

Comment: Nice, but your consideration of  cardinality is irrelevant.  The question was not to imbed $V \subset W$ so that $V$ is not isomorphic to $W$.   The question was to imbed $V$ in $W$ so that $V \ne W$.

Comment: I interpreted "a bigger vector space" as  "one that is bigger in dimension".  Of course you are absolutely right, that was a assumption on my part. Thanks for pointing me to it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question requires only one line, and it does not require using a basis, or considering cardinality.

Let $V$ be denote your vector space over a field $F$.  Let $X$ be any non-zero vector space over $F$, for example $X = F$ if you like.  Then $V$ imbeds in $W = V \oplus X$ via $v \mapsto (v, 0)$, with image $V \oplus (0) \subsetneq W$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let $V$ be any vector space your heart desires. Let $\beta$ be a basis for $V.$ Let $\vec{s}$ be a formal symbol, which we will regard as linearly independent of the vectors in $\beta.$ Then $\beta\cup \{\vec{s}\}$ is a basis for some "new" vector space, and 
$$V\subset \text{span}(\beta\cup \{\vec{s}\})$$
and $V$ is proper, nontrivial.

Answer (score 0):

First the usual bit: if $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$, then (knowing that $F$ is a vector space over itself) you can construct the vector space $V\times F$, in which elements are pairs from the Cartesian product $V\times F$ and the operations are defined coordinate-wise, i.e. $(v_1, \alpha_1)+(v_2, \alpha_2)=(v_1+v_2, \alpha_1+\alpha_2)$, $\lambda(v,\alpha)=(\lambda v, \lambda\alpha)$.

(Note: Instead of $F$, I could use any other nontrivial vector space over $F$, but let's be specific for the purpose of this answer.)

**Now, is $V$ a proper subspace of $V\times F$?**

What is obvious is that there is an injective homomorphism $V\to V\times F$, mapping $v\in V$ to $(v,0_F)\in V\times F$. Thus we can say that we can *"identify"* $V$ with its image $V\times\{0_F\}$, and we can *"see"* $V$ as a proper subspace of $V\times F$. Namely, $V$ is then isomorphic to $V\times\{0_F\}$ and the latter is a proper subspace, knowing that it does not contain $(0_V, 1_F)$.

**Okay, but isn't this a bit hand-wavy?**

After all, $V$ is $V$ and $V\times\{0_F\}$ is $V\times\{0_F\}$, we didn't really *extend* $V$ but have made something *else*, that looks pretty much as $V$, contained in a bigger vector space.

The answer is obvious when you look at it, but is rarely given up to detail. We will actually take the set $V\times F$, *cut out* the image of the injective homomorphism ($V\times\{0_F\}$), and *add* the actual $V$. In other words, we will define a new set:

$$\overline{V}=((V\times F)\setminus(V\times\{0_F\}))\cup V$$

On *that* set we need to define the operations to "stitch together" $V$ with the rest of the set difference $(V\times F)\setminus(V\times\{0_F\})$: for all $x,y\in\overline{V}$:

$$x+y:=\begin{cases}x+y&x,y\in V\\(x+w,\beta)&x\in V,y=(w,\beta)\in V\times F,\beta\ne 0_F\\(v+y,\alpha)&x=(v,\alpha)\in V\times F, \alpha\ne 0_F, y\in V\\(v+w, \alpha+\beta)&x=(v,\alpha)\in V\times F, y=(w,\beta)\in V\times F, \alpha,\beta,\alpha+\beta\ne 0_F\\v+w\in V&x=(v,\alpha)\in V\times F, y=(w,\beta)\in V\times F, \alpha,\beta\ne 0_F,\alpha+\beta=0_F\end{cases}$$

and:

$$\lambda x:=\begin{cases} \lambda x\in V&x\in V\\(\lambda v,\lambda\alpha) & x=(v,\alpha)\in V\times F, \alpha\ne 0_F\end{cases}$$

Now these operations need to be proven to be well defined, and $\overline{V}$ would need to be proven to be a vector space over $F$, i.e. that all the vector space axioms are satisfied. That is why you'll rarely see it done - it is very tedious, it will need to distinguish a lot of cases, and at the end of the day, all you learn is what you intuitively already knew, in the "hand-wavy" way, that it will extend $V$ to a properly containing vector space $\overline{V}$. Hope you will forgive me for also omitting this tedious proof.

Comment: Will take me some time to digest this answer, but I forgive you in advance ;) Thx!

Comment: Making an effort to make $W$ literally contain $V$  is not in the spirit of most of mathematics. We don't do that when we construct the field of fractions of an integral domain, when we complete a metric space, when we construct algebraic extensions of a field, including when we construct the complex numbers from the reals, etc.

Comment: @fredgoodman Fully agreed. However, I believe that the very fact we can consider isomorphic structure as being “the same”, so we don’t worry about one substituting for the other, is basically underpinned by the same reasoning I’ve tried to demonstrate here. If you *really* want to substitute them, you *can*.